# A lucrative partnership expression "fullfruit partnership"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In an old movie there was a dinner party with a group of English executives. One of them mentioned the expression "fullfruit partnership". Is this a common expression in the business world or is it an old expression?

Comment: I wonder if you meant 'fruitful partnership', since 'fullfruit partnership' does not mean anything.

Comment: I do not know if I understood correctly because I am still studying and I only heard the expression. I understand something like "partnership that will bring us many fruits"

Comment: It could a joke fullfruit instead of fruitful.

Comment: It could be anything.

Comment: Incidentally, "producing fruit" is something beneficial. Which is where the phrase comes from. (In other words, "Those apple trees are full of fruit—they are fruitful." As opposed to those which did not produce fruit and aren't being helpful.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably heard  'fruitful partnership', since 'fullfruit partnership' does not mean anything.

> fruitful
>
> 1.1 Producing good or helpful results; productive.

[Fruitful (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fruitful)

Comment: It could be a kind of spoonerism, too. It could be humorous.